Request.QueryString variable values
I need to be able to read a Form set of inputs into a request.querystring, but the number of records may change.
I am trying to avoid this:
q1=request("Q1")
q2=request("Q2")
...
...
So, if I have a db table of 10 questions, and those values are in a form for input\update.
I want to be able to read the values of those fields back to a Request.QueryString and update the db.
Each input from the db results are Q1 - Qn (n=10 today), needs to be read dynamically, so if I add a question tomorrow, n=11, I don't have to change the querystring to add a new row.
I assume I am looking at a loop to build the request string, but I can't see how.
Hope that's clear.
Thanks
A number of syntactically incorrect loops.
The page works, but no values are returned.
